# How can I sum up values from multiple rows that have one variable in common (R)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 12
  geo_ID age_group sex   rep_date   ref_date   ref_rep_date new_case new_death new_recovery amount_case amount_death amount_recovery
   <dbl> <fct>     <fct> <date>     <date>     <lgl>           <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>
1   2000 A15-A34   M     2020-09-24 2020-09-18 TRUE                0        -9            0           1            0               1
2   2000 A35-A59   W     2022-03-30 2022-03-24 TRUE                0        -9           -9           1            0               0
3   2000 A15-A34   W     2021-08-03 2021-07-28 TRUE                0        -9            0           3            0               3
4   2000 A05-A14   W     2021-10-14 2021-10-12 TRUE                0        -9            0           1            0               1
5   2000 A35-A59   M     2020-11-06 2020-11-01 TRUE                0        -9            0           4            0               4
```

I then used `dplyr` to do the following:

```
inf_HH %>% select(ref_date, new_case, starts_with("amount")) %>% 
  filter(new_case != 0 & amount_death == 0 & amount_recovery == 0) %>% 
  select(ref_date, ends_with("case")) %>% arrange(desc(ref_date))
```

and get this tibble out (with `%>% slice_sample(n = 20)` appended):

```
# A tibble: 20 × 3
   ref_date   new_case amount_case
   <date>        <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 2022-04-02       -1          -1
 2 2022-04-07        1          58
 3 2022-04-07       -1          -1
 4 2022-04-12        1           1
 5 2022-04-04        1           2
 6 2022-04-07        1          10
 7 2022-04-12        1           2
 8 2022-04-11        1          23
 9 2022-04-10        1           1
10 2022-04-12       -1          -1
11 2022-04-10        1           1
12 2022-04-03        1           1
13 2022-04-04        1           1
14 2022-04-13        1           8
15 2022-04-07        1          41
16 2022-04-01        1           1
17 2022-04-08        1           5
18 2022-04-04        1           1
19 2022-04-09        1           1
20 2022-04-07        1           1
```

Without `%>% slice_sample(n = 20)` it has 183 rows, where `ref_date` has 19 unique values.

What I am trying to achieve is to sum up all values in `amount_case` for each unique value in `ref_date`.

What I have been trying to do is use `distinct` to make progress:

```
inf_HH %>% select(ref_date, new_case, starts_with("amount")) %>% 
  filter(new_case != 0 & amount_death == 0 & amount_recovery == 0) %>% 
  select(ref_date, ends_with("case")) %>% arrange(desc(ref_date)) %>% 
  distinct(ref_date, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

What I get is:

```
# A tibble: 19 × 3
   ref_date   new_case amount_case
   <date>        <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 2022-04-14        1          10
 2 2022-04-13        1          28
 3 2022-04-12       -1          -2
 4 2022-04-11       -1          -1
 5 2022-04-10       -1          -1
 6 2022-04-09        1           1
 7 2022-04-08        1           6
 8 2022-04-07        1           1
 9 2022-04-06        1           1
10 2022-04-05        1           2
11 2022-04-04        1           1
12 2022-04-03        1           1
13 2022-04-02       -1          -1
14 2022-04-01        1           1
15 2022-03-30        1           1
16 2022-03-28        1           1
17 2022-03-24        1           1
18 2022-03-22       -1          -1
19 2022-03-21        1           1
```

I would like to extend the dplyr-piping so that I get a tibble like the last one above but with the sums of all the values in `amount_case` for each unique value in `ref_date`.

Another way, which I cannot express in R, would be to somehow use `group_by()` with `summarise()` but I cannot find a way to use them to group rows *AND* add the values in `amount_case`.

Preferably this should happen with `tidyverse` / `dplyr` packages, which I am sort of comfortable with. I need to do the same operation on hundreds of other datasets, with similar structure, so it is out of question to address the unique values of `ref_date` manually.

Comment: `inf_HH %>% group_by(ref_date) %>% summarize(amount_case  = sum(amount_case))`?

Comment: Thank you, that's actually exactly what I wanted.